Subcontractor (me) is getting "70%" of the payment given to main contractor. Is this a good deal?
I work as a subcontractor for a freelance IT firm. I have specialized work that they don't do, but when such work comes up, they hire me to do it for them.
I was told I would be paid 70% of what they charge the client, as I'm doing all the work but they're giving me the business. I was happy with this number, because they charge more than I usually do as a solo-contractor, and I end up making the same if not more money when I receive the 70% cut from them. This payment structure includes a one-time payout, and monthly payouts.
In the latest project, I noticed the monthly payout was 15% less than what I expected.
I'm realizing the flaw in this system, because I can't control what he is going to charge, so I can never know what I'm going to get from a project, only that it's 70% of what he is charging.
In previous projects, I had made contracts with a fixed dollar amount, based on that 70%. For this latest project, there was no contract, and I was expecting it to be based on the previous contract, as that's what we verbally agreed to. My mistake.
I am wondering if it's wise to abandon the 70% deal altogether, and just ask for fixed dollar amounts. This would make it so much easier to invoice for, but I could be missing out on more money in the future. I also want to keep him happy, because he gives me a lot of business that is profitable to me. My fixed rates might be more than 70% in some cases, which he might decline.

70% sounds like a good deal. Many business models allocate 20-30% of the bill rate to sales and marketing. That doesn't leave anything for their profit.

How is 15% less than you expected to be related to anything else, please? Since you raised the '15%' Question, what's your explanation in terms of simple arithmetic - and how does that relate to the contract?

If it were me, I'd suggest a fixed hourly rate payment schedule. I don't care what you charge your client so long as you pay me $xx.xx per hour for my work.
The problem with your being paid 70% of what they charge the client is that you have no control over what they charge the client, and ultimately, what you'll be paid for a given project or piece of work. What if they charge the client $10.00 per hour? Are you OK with being paid $7.00 per hour?
Not to mention that they could lowball you by simply telling you they charged the client less than they actually did.

Subcontracting or not.... I charge what I charge.
If someone wants to work as an "agent" for me and find work, deal with clients, etc. I'm willing to offer them a discount on my rates. But I still charge what I charge.
If an "agent" wishes to markup my rates an additional %, that's their call and has nothing to do with me. Chasing what the agent may be charging is a fools errand. Run your business, don't take scraps others are willing to give you. You should have financial/income goals. Charge what you need to charge to meet those goals.
It's best to try and overcome the "fear of missing out" feeling and just set the rate you want to earn and charge that. Forget about what any agent may be charging others. The agent may be offering discounts and deals you never would - thus you earn 15% less than you feel you should if you rely on the pricing set by an agent.
Example using arbitrary amounts: I charge $1,000 for a project. Someone wants to work as my agent, so I'll discount my rate to $850... the agent is then responsible for paying that $850 for my work. If the agent bills someone else $1,100 for the work (making $250), they can.... just so long  as I get my $850.
My payment is never dependent upon what the agent is charging or even if the agent gets paid by someone else. My contract is with the agent for $850. The agent is responsible for my payment.
The largest mistake I made when I started out was to allow the "when they pay me, I'll pay you" mindset. I don't do that any more, and haven't for a long time. I expect to get paid, even if the agent ends up getting "stiffed" by some client. I'm doing the work. I expect to get paid for my work.
If I have to depend on some undisclosed third party payment.... The agent is more likely to let a non-paying client slide - giving up their small % ($250) in the overhead they added and not care if I miss out on the bulk of the fees ($850). I have much more to lose due to non-payment than any agent ever will.
I ensure the agent is vested in payment by being responsible for my fees. In addition, as a subcontractor, you generally have no legal standing to collect from any non-paying third party. The third party may not even know you exist.
In short, take control. Set your rates and make the agent agree to be responsible for your fees, not their clients. It ensures the agent is acting with your best interests in mind as well as their own.

it depends on the contract signed but I would push for a signed contract always, without a contract they can well, there's no nicer way I know of to say this, f**k you, UNLESS, you make verbal contracts, both parts need to record you agreeing to the statement. and agreeing on pay, basically a contract and if your basing it on a past contract yo will want to have that past contract on hand incase something legal happens

Ah so this is where ya came from, :)
